# Finding a function that satisfies $3$ given equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a $\mathbb{R}$-linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, so that:
$$f\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\quad f\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}\quad f\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$

Would $f\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y+1\end{pmatrix}$ be the minimalistical answer to that?

Comment: Are you trying to write $f(1,1)=(1,2)$, $f(1,2)=(1,3)$ etc.

Comment: hi, the excercise uses the vector notation with 1 vertical over 1 etc. Does your notation mean basicly the same?

Comment: Yes. You can write vectors vertically, but it is more cumbersome to do.

Comment: @saturatedexpo I tried to correct it, hope I got it right. If you want to correct something, you will find instruction about the MathJax interface at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Some has already edited it so take a look at the code they used. But like almagest said, it's quicker to just write them side by side as an ordered pair rather than a vector. If you really really want to make it vertical, you can use the code or write $(x \,\, y)^\mathrm{T}$ to indicate the transpose of $(x \,\, y)$, which is the same as $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y+1\end{pmatrix}$ certainly does what you ask; but it is not actually a linear transformation, as
$$f\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\neq \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

If you want a linear transformation you need to define it as
$$f\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ x+y\end{pmatrix}$$
instead.

Comment: so linear only means any function which has exactly one value for any "input"?

Comment: No, linear means $f(ax + by) = a f(x) + b f(y)$ for scalars $a,b$ and vectors $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $u = \pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr}$ and $v = \pmatrix{1\cr 2\cr}$ are a basis of $\mathbb R^2$, so the values of a linear function there uniquely determine that linear function.  Now we only need the given value of $f$ at $w = \pmatrix{1\cr 3\cr}$ to be consistent with this.  Well, $w = 2v-u$, and 
you can check that $f(w) = 2 f(v) - f(u)$, so yes, it is consistent.  The answer is yes, there is such a linear function.